# Dynamic namespace usage based on a template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, boost, namespaces, typedef

I don't know if that is feasable at all, but this is what I'd like to achieve : in a templated class I would like to be using the namespace of the template parameter.

eg.

```
template<class P>
class Foo
{
    public:
        Foo();
        virtual ~Foo();

        void doSomething(P&);
        void doSomethingElse();

    protected:
        // There I'm hardcoding "namespace1" but that's what I'd like to 
        // be possibly dynamic 
        // (I'm assuming template parameter P = namespace1::Type)
        void method1(namespace1::Type1&);
        ...
        void methodN(namespace1::TypeN&);
}

// Again, supposing P == namespace1::Type then I want to be using namespace1 
// everywhere in the implementation...
using namespace namespace1;

template<class P>
void Foo<P>::doSomething(P& parameter)
{
    ...
    Type1 type1 = P.getType1(); // There namespace1::Type1 is returned !!
    method1(type1);
    ...
}

template<class P>
void Foo<P>::doSomethingElse()
{
    ...
    TypeN typen; // There I want to instanciate a namespace1::TypeN !!
    ...
}

...
```

Of course I don't want to specialize the template and provide a dedicated implementation for every possible `P` value as well as I'd like to avoid passing all the types like `Type1` and `TypeN` as template parameters since I potentially have lots of them.

Is that possible ?

The project is C++3 based, any boost solution is welcome.

**Update**

Being the template parameter `P` itself exactly like any `TypeN` parameter, this could be the right approach :

```
template<typename NAMESPACE>
class Foo
{
    typedef typename NAMESPACE::Parameter MyParameter; 
    typedef typename NAMESPACE::Type1 MyType1; 
    typedef typename NAMESPACE::Type1 MyTypeN; 
    ...
}
```

Comment: Are you willing to add some stuff into each namespace that may be used?

Comment: What is the relationship between `P`, `Type1`... `TypeN`. In some cases it could make sense to encode that relationship into `P` itself in a nested type. Then you can just use `typename P::Type1` and that will resolve to the appropriate `Type1` for `P`.

Comment: It's very likely that what you need to achieve does not require this as a solution. Can you clarify why do you think you need it?

Comment: Reading Matthieu's answer I actually realized I can solve it easier that that, so @AndyProwl you were probably right! I'm going to update the question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes and No.

Yes it is possible to *deduce* secondary types from a primary one, generally using a trait system:

```
template <typename T> struct Trait { typedef typename T::Secondary Secondary; };

template <typename X>
struct Foo {
    typedef typename Trait<X>::Secondary Secondary;

    void foo(Secondary const& s);
};
```

No, you cannot deduce a *namespace*, and thus cannot *use* it; but note how by using a local alias (`typedef ...`) within the class there is no need to.

Comment: Traits are indeed the common way to deal with associations between types, but you should probably add that the advantage of using traits is that they can be specialized to support any types, even those who do not define the appropriate inner typedefs.

Comment: However, I disagree with you when you say that a namespace cannot be deduced: ADL is a sort of namespace deduction, even though you cannot directly manipulate the namespace.

Comment: @LucTouraille: for the usage the OP asked for (naming the types of function arguments) using ADL would be quite cumbersome.

Comment: You got a typo on your last sentence :) `decuce`

Comment: @VG: Oops! Thanks :D

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to add a structure inside each namespace that lists all the types you need, you can then rely on ADL to get this structure depending on a template parameter:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

namespace Foo_ns
{
    struct T1
    {
        static void m() { std::cout << "Foo_ns::T1" << '\n'; }
    };
    struct Foo {};

    // List of all the types you need from this namespace
    struct Types
    {
        typedef Foo_ns::T1 T1;        
    };

    // dummy function needed for ADL        
    Types types(...);
}

namespace Bar_ns
{
    struct T1
    {
        static void m() { std::cout << "Bar_ns::T1" << '\n'; }
    };
    struct Bar {};

    struct Types
    {
        typedef Bar_ns::T1 T1;
    };

    Types types(...);
}

template <typename T>
void callMOnT1(const T &arg)
{
    typedef decltype(types(std::declval<T>())) Types; // ADL kicks in
    //typedef typename std::result_of<types(T)>::type Types;
    Types::T1::m();
}

int main()
{
    callMOnT1((Bar_ns::Bar())); // Bar_ns::T1
    callMOnT1((Foo_ns::Foo())); // Foo_ns::T1
}
```

Unfortunately, this solution using some C++11 features (namely `decltype` and `declval`). For some reason, I didn't manage to get the code working with `result_of`, which is present in Boost (perhaps someone could explain why the code with `result_of` does not compile?).

Answer (score 0):

No that is impossible,but you can use ugly macro file.

```
//my_class.inl
template<TYPE_ARG>
struct my_class_t<TYPE_ARG>
{
   foo()
   {
      NS_ARG::bar();
   }
}

//my.h
template<class T>
struct my_class_t{};

#define TYPE_ARG T1
#define NS_ARG std
#include "my_class.inl"

#define TYPE_ARG T2
#define NS_ARG boost
#include "my_class.inl"

#undef TYPE_ARG
#undef NS_ARG
```

That way you will automate class specialisation for different namespaces. Do you really need this? :o)

Comment: Also you may want to pack all your types to traits... :)